# Getting a parent model object

Tags: wpf, telerik

Here is my issue.I have a DataTemplate inside the content part of a RadTileViewItem. Each ViewItem has a model object with various properties. Inside the DataTemplate is a button. When this is clicked, I would like to be able to get access to the RadTileViewItem's model object. How would I go about doing this? I don't know how I'd know what parent each button is inside of in order to get it's model object.

ViewModel:

```
class TCardViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<TCardBase> items;

    public TCardViewModel()
    {

        List<TCardBase> itemsSource = new List<TCardBase>();

        CFETSDBContainer ctx = new CFETSDBContainer();
        foreach (var incident in ctx.INCIDENTs)
        {
            itemsSource.Add(new TCardBase()
            {
                IncidentName = incident.IncidentName,
                Desginator = "Desig",
                Location = "Lat:"+incident.Latitude+",Lon:"+incident.Longitude,
            });


        } 
        this.items = new ObservableCollection<TCardBase>(itemsSource);
    }






public ObservableCollection<TCardBase> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
    }


}


<telerik:RadTileView Name="MainRadTileView"                       
                        IsItemDraggingEnabled="{Binding ElementName=IsItemDraggingEnabledOption,Path=IsChecked}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TCardTemplateSelector}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}"
                        MaximizeMode="{Binding ElementName=MaximizeModeOption,Path=SelectedItem}"
                        PreservePositionWhenMaximized="{Binding ElementName=PreservePositionWhenMaximizedOption,Path=IsChecked}"
                        TileStateChanged="tileView1_TileStateChanged"
                        TileStateChangeTrigger="{Binding ElementName=StateChangeOption, Path=SelectedItem}"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="IncidentContentTemplate">
        <telerik:RadFluidContentControl ContentChangeMode="Manual"
                                        State="Normal"
                                        TransitionDuration="0:0:.5">
            <telerik:RadFluidContentControl.Content>
                <Border Background="Red">
                    <Grid Margin="20 10">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Margin="0 0 0 5"
                                       FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                       FontSize="24"
                                       FontWeight="Light"
                                       Foreground="#fff"
                                       Text="Designator" />
                            <TextBlock FontSize="14" 
                                       Foreground="{telerik:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=AccentBrush}"
                                       Text="{Binding Desginator}" />
                            <Border Height="2"
                                    Margin="0 5" 
                                    Background="{telerik:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=AccentBrush}" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="0 0 0 5"
                                       FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                       FontSize="24"
                                       FontWeight="Light"
                                       Foreground="#fff"
                                       Text="Location" />
                            <TextBlock FontSize="14" 
                                       Foreground="{telerik:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=AccentBrush}"
                                       Text="{Binding Location}" />
                        </StackPanel> 
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </telerik:RadFluidContentControl.Content>

            <telerik:RadFluidContentControl.LargeContent>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="360" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!--   <Image Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                           Source="{Binding Image}"
                           Stretch="None" />-->
                    <Button Width="200" Height="200" Content="View" Click="LoadTCard_Clicked"></Button>
                    <StackPanel Margin="35 205 0 0" Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <TextBlock FontSize="30"
                                   Foreground="#FFFFFF"
                                   Text="{Binding Desginator}" />
                        <TextBlock FontSize="30"
                                   Foreground="#FFFFFF"
                                   Text="" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="15 155 0 0"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   Foreground="#FFFFFF"
                                   Text="{Binding Desginator}" />
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   Foreground="#FFFFFF"
                                   Text="@trips.com" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="70 50 0 0">
                        <TextBlock Margin="0 0 0 5"
                                   FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   Foreground="{telerik:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=AccentBrush}"
                                   Text="2011 Oct 28th, 2011 Nov 3th" />
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                   FontSize="14" 
                                   Foreground="{telerik:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=AccentBrush}"
                                   Text="1011 Nov 11th, 2011 Dec 2nd" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="0 72 0 0"
                                   FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   Foreground="{telerik:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=AccentBrush}"
                                   Text="{Binding IncidentName}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="0 74 0 0"
                                   FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   Foreground="{telerik:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=AccentBrush}"
                                   Text="{Binding Location}" />

                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>
            </telerik:RadFluidContentControl.LargeContent>
        </telerik:RadFluidContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Might help to provide your xaml -- I doubt many people are fluent with this particular telerik control.

Comment: I thought there may be a generic WPF way of doing it I was missing. Posted xaml. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just use something like `((Button)sender).DataContext as TCardBase` ?

Comment: That is what I needed. Thanks a lot McGarnagle!